# Does IBM Websphere support SQL server 2008

Tags: java, websphere

Currently I am with IBM Websphere 5.1 and SQL server 2000. I need to migrate from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008. Currently I think Websphere 5.1 does not support SQL Server 2008.

Is there any fix or way around to migrate my SQL server without changing current version of websphere??

Also Which version of Websphere support SQL Server 2008?

Thanks

Comment: maybe we should move this question to serverfault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WebSphere Application Server versions
>   prior to V6.1 were written to be
>   compatible with the Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2000 database. However,
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2005 is not fully
>   forward compatible from Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2000, and therefore WebSphere
>   Application Server versions prior to
>   V6.1 are not fully compatible with
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Taken from IBM's [site](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21254636).

Comment: Thanks Neil, Can you tell me which exact version of websphere should we use in order to migrate the DB from SQL Server 2000 to 2008?

Comment: You can use SQL Server 2005 and 2008 with 6.0, according to this link: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rdat_minreqmssql.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that WAS 5.1 is no longer supported.

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?synkey=C578916B44100K52-T136169P16066X41-I069483T99009M25

It has been out of support for close to three years now. You are better off upgrading WAS to a supported version (which might support the SQL Server versions you are after)

HTH

Manglu